# Marklogic java client-api exception via shadow jar build via gradle

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-8

I am using marklogic java client-api to extract documents and it works fine when doing in my intellij, but when I build a shadow jar and run it I get the following exception

```
com.sun.jersey.api.client.RequestWriter$RequestEntityWriterImpl <init>
SEVERE: A message body writer for Java class com.marklogic.client.impl.StreamingOutputImpl, and Java type class com.marklogic.client.impl.StreamingOutputImpl, and MIME media type application/xml was not found
Jul 07, 2016 5:29:53 PM com.sun.jersey.api.client.RequestWriter$RequestEntityWriterImpl <init>
SEVERE: The registered message body writers compatible with the MIME media type are:
```

I am building the shadow jar using gradle.. and my `build.gradle` look lik the following

```
buildscript {
    repositories { jcenter() }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.github.jengelman.gradle.plugins:shadow:1.2.3'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'wrapper'
apply plugin: 'com.github.johnrengelman.shadow'

sourceCompatibility = 1.7
targetCompatibility = 1.7

repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    maven {
        url "http://nexus.abbvienet.com/content/groups/public"
    }
}

import com.github.jengelman.gradle.plugins.shadow.transformers.AppendingTransformer
shadowJar {
    transform(AppendingTransformer) {
        resource = 'META-INF/services'
    }

}

dependencies {
    compile 'org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.12'
    compile 'ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:1.1.3'
    compile 'com.moonlight:lfsappenders:4.0.3'
    compile group: 'org.apache.commons', name: 'commons-lang3', version: '3.0'
    compile group: 'commons-io', name: 'commons-io', version: '2.4'
    compile group: 'org.apache.commons', name: 'commons-collections4', version: '4.0'
    compile group: 'com.google.code.gson', name: 'gson', version: '2.3'
    compile group: 'com.marklogic', name: 'java-client-api', version: '3.0.1'
    compile group: 'dom4j', name: 'dom4j', version: '1.6.1'
    compile group: 'org.jdom', name: 'jdom2', version: '2.0.5'
    compile group: 'xom', name: 'xom', version: '1.2.5'
    compile group: 'jaxen', name: 'jaxen', version: '1.1.6'
    compile group: 'net.sourceforge.htmlcleaner', name: 'htmlcleaner', version: '2.4'
    compile group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents', name: 'httpclient', version: '4.4.1'
    compile group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents', name: 'httpmime', version: '4.4.1'
    compile group: 'joda-time', name: 'joda-time', version: '2.9.4'
}
```

I am thinking it has to do with my tramsform ... Am I missing something ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve my issue.. the issue that was causing the error is the merging of META-INF/services from various jars.. And in my `build.gradle` I was using the wrong transform .. I changed the following from the above build.gradle and everything worked..

The original section

```
import com.github.jengelman.gradle.plugins.shadow.transformers.AppendingTransformer

        shadowJar {
            transform(AppendingTransformer) {
                resource = 'META-INF/services'
            }

        }
```

Changed to the following

```
shadowJar {
    mergeServiceFiles()
}
```

I was using the wrong transform.. I needed to merge all my service files..